# ng-token-auth Registration promise not resolving with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I have managed to set up ng-token-auth with ionic(angular) and devise-token-auth with rails however when I create a User no error is logged in the rails console and the the user is created.

The user is created in the database however I have designed the ionic user controller to login the user once the registration is complete by using a promise. The controller is below:

```
comeDineApp.controller('userController', ['ipCookie','$scope', '$state', '$auth',
function(ipCookie, $scope, $state, $auth){

  $scope.handleRegBtnClick = function() {
    console.log("hello")
    $auth.submitRegistration($scope.registrationForm)
    .then(function() {
      console.log("welcome")
      $auth.submitLogin({
        email: $scope.registrationForm.email,
        password: $scope.registrationForm.password
      });
    });
  };
}]);
```

In this case the submitLogin function doesn't execute as the promise is not resolved even though the user is successfully created in the DB.

My rails user model is below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
  :confirmable, :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  has_many :tables

before_save -> do
  self.uid = SecureRandom.uuid
  skip_confirmation!
end
```

end
and my user controller is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :json

  def show
    render json: current_user.tables
  end
end
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this either in the rails or the angular so that  the angular promise resolves to login directly after signing up?

Comment: i have the same issue, are you able to solve it?

Comment: no solution, have you found one?